# Creating an associative array from grep results in bash

Tags: bash, grep, associative-array

I am using the following loc in a bash script to return unique grep result strings and their counts:

```
 hitStrings="$(eval 'find "$DIR" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -roh "\w*$searchWord\w*"' | sort | uniq -c)"
```

For example, if I have a $searchWord of "you", I could get the following results:

> 5 Kougyou 2 Layout 10 layouts 2330 you 859 your 17 yourself

My questions are:

1. How to I created an associative array containing the strings that are returned as the keys, and their counts as the values?
2. How do I omit the initial searchWord and its count from the associative array above (so no you-859 when I search for "you")?

Thanks

Comment: How can you get `Layout` when your have `\w` around your query?

Comment: I assume \w just returns whole words.

Comment: @jambox:bash has [associative arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arrays) since v4.0 (released 2009).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have too many unnecessary layers, you can achieve the same with

```
$ grep -roh "\w*$key\w*" | sort | uniq -c > counts
```

and

```
$ declare -A counts; while read -r v k; do counts[$k]=$v; done < counts
$ echo ${counts["you"]}
```

Note that depends on the usage, you may get away by the file itself.  Again searching for "you" count from the file

```
$ awk -v key="you" '$2==key{print $1}' counts
```

if the same name confuses you change one of them, or remove the temp file altogether by substitution.

```
$ declare -A counts
$ while read -r v k; do counts[$k]=$v; done < <(grep -roh "\w*$key\w*" | sort | uniq -c)
```

or with evil `eval` you can do

```
$ eval declare -A counts=( $(grep -roh "\w*$key\w*" | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print "["$2"]="$1}') )
```

but why?  The while loop is a perfectly fine solution.

Comment: So to your knowledge there isn't a way to assign the results of the grep statement, and some cut-foo to an associative array?

Comment: I have one issue with this, sometimes I am grepping for two words like "to give". When I create the associative array, it provides a key value pair for both "to" and its count and "give" and its count, instead of "to give" and its count (though the count is correct)

Comment: no, it's not going to work, since assumes space as a delimiter. `\w*$key\w*' pattern doesn't make sense if your key has spaces... Regardless, in this case replace `awk` with this `sed -E 's/([0-9]+)\s+(.*)/[\2]=\1/'`